# Windows 11 WPF dark titlebar doesnt work 'interop helper missing'

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

Hello I am trying to get the DarkMode titlebar in my WPF app to work but it says that InteropHelper is not found and I cant find anything online.

I followed [this tutorial](https://codingguides.quinnscomputing.com/2022/05/how-to-enable-dark-title-bar-in-windows.html)

```cs
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = true)]
        public static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, ref bool attrValue, int attrSize);        
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            var value = true;
            InteropHelper.DwmSetWindowAttribute(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, 20, ref value, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(true));
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?

Comment: Search computer for file.  It may be the project settings.  DLL may need to run in x86 mode if it is 32 bit.  The file may be in the System32 folder or the SysWOW64

Comment: `Marshal.SizeOf(true)` is 4 or 8 in C#, depending on your architecture, but `sizeof(bool)` is 1 in C++. Are you absolutely certain you know what you're doing?

Comment: @Blindy I followed the tutorial above, Is this not correct?

Comment: Does it look correct to you? It doesn't even run.

Comment: @Blindy That's the tutorial and it's also specified above that "InteropHelper" is not found

Comment: You wouldn’t have a handle for a window in its constructor either. One would typically override the OnSourceInitialized and then get it within that and do your initialization.

Comment: Also InteropHelper is likely the name of the class where they defined that static extern. In your case it seems like its in the same class as the Window so you don’t need the "InteropHelper."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn P/Invoke a bit.

1. You need to get the window handle of a WPF's `Window` typically by [WindowInteropHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper).
2. The window handle is not valid yet at the time of `Window`'s constructor as AndrewS commented. So, you need to wait for `Window.SourceInitialized` event. OR you need to use [WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.ensurehandle) method if you want it inside the constructor.

The way to call `DwmSetWindowAttribute` function is briefly touched in [Apply rounded corners in desktop apps for Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners), the attribute is different though.

A sample code would be:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("Dwmapi.dll")]
    private static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(
        IntPtr hwnd,
        DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE attribute,
        [In] ref bool pvAttribute,
        int cbAttribute);

    private enum DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE
    {
        DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE = 20,
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).EnsureHandle();
        bool value = true;
        int result = DwmSetWindowAttribute(
            hWnd,
            DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE.DWMWA_USE_IMMERSIVE_DARK_MODE,
            ref value,
            Marshal.SizeOf<bool>());

        Debug.WriteLine(result); // 0 means success.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not the proper solution to your problem, there is a way to control the color of the titlebar, and you could better match it to a theme if that is what you are looking for, this could also give you an idea of how to do the above correctly.

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
private static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, int[] attrValue, int attrSize);
const int DWWMA_CAPTION_COLOR = 35;

public MainWindow()
{
    IntPtr hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).EnsureHandle();
    int[] colorstr = new int[] { 0x000 };
    DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWWMA_CAPTION_COLOR, colorstr, 4);
}
```